# Why would svgs show up resized (in an undesirable way) on reload, but render properly on force reload?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I'm running into a bug with svgs resizing in an unexpected (and undesirable) way. The icons are styled to look like this:
[image]

and they only show up properly if I reload the page using cmd+shift+R. If I reload with just cmd+R, they end up smaller:
[image]

They are supposed to be 15x15px, but the inspector shows that their width is much smaller.
[image]

Would really appreciate any suggestions/ideas on what's going on! (And please let me know if there's other information I should provide--this is my first question on here.)

Edit to show code:

svg file:

```
<svg width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 13 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="6" width="13" height="7">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0H12.9001V6.68354H0V0Z" transform="translate(0 6.31641)" fill="white"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0)">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0.434174 0H12.3966C12.3966 0 13.2083 0.0625625 12.7712 0.967687L11.2404 5.96537C11.2404 5.96537 11.147 6.43337 10.3979 6.65275L2.46461 6.68362C2.46461 6.68362 1.90236 6.65275 1.49611 5.87194L0.0279237 0.8125C0.0279237 0.8125 -0.158951 0.156 0.434174 0Z" transform="translate(-0.000244141 6.31641)" fill="#818F6E"/>
</g>
<mask id="mask1" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="0" width="11" height="7">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0H9.96288V6.09212H0V0Z" transform="translate(1.43335 0.566406)" fill="white"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask1)">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 6.09229C0 6.08986 0.0836876 -0.120893 5.06025 0.00179403C9.672 0.116357 9.96288 6.05898 9.96288 6.06061L8.46381 5.93629C8.46381 5.93386 8.45487 1.37492 5.02856 1.28229C1.6445 1.19129 1.59331 5.93386 1.5925 5.93629L0 6.09229Z" transform="translate(1.43335 0.566406)" fill="#818F6E"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

icon:

```
<FollowersWrapper
    follows={follows ? 1 : 0}
    onClick={() => toggleFollow()}
  >
    <StatIcon src={follows ? following : notFollowing} alt="Followers" />
    {followersCount}
  </FollowersWrapper>
```

styles:

```
export const StatIcon = styled.img`
height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  padding-top: 3px;
`
export const FollowersWrapper = styled(Flex)`
  color: ${props =>
    props.follows
      ? themeGet('colors.highlight')
      : themeGet('colors.secondaryDarkVariant')};
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  letter-spacing: 1.33px;
  font-family: ${themeGet('fonts.tabs.family')};

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`
```

Comment: you should provide the code

Comment: Can it be issues with the viewBox of the svg itself?

Comment: Or it could be a browser bug. Does this happen on all browsers?

Comment: Updated question to provide relevant snippets. And it happens on both Chrome and Safari. :/